# Mapping properties of the complex inversion $1/z$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

This is from the text Complex Variables with Applications by Herb Silverman.

We present some precise mapping properties of $w=1/z$. Consider the circle $|z-a|=R, a\neq 0$. If $w=1/z$, then we obtain that 
$$|z-a|\lt R \iff |\frac{1}{w}-a|\lt R \iff |1-aw|^2 \lt R^2|w|^2 \iff $$
$$|w|^2(|a|^2-R^2)-2Re(aw)+1 \lt 0.
 \iff 
\begin{cases}
Re(aw)\gt 1/2,  & \text{for R=|a|} \\
|w-\frac{\bar a}{|a|^2-R^2}|\lt \frac{R}{|a|^2-R^2}, & \text{for R < |a|} \\
|w-\frac{\bar a}{|a|^2-R^2}|\gt \frac{R}{R^2-|a|^2}, & \text{for R > |a|}
\end{cases}$$

What I don't understand here is the final two lines in the braced part. I don't see how the author came up with the final two strict inequalities from the previous inequality. I'd appreciate it if anyone could explain this to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Wikipedia :http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle#Complex_plane 
 
The equation of a generalized circle in complex plane is given by :
 $pz{\bar z}+ gz + \bar{gz}= q$ , where $p,q\in \mathbb{R}$ and $g \in \mathbb{C}$
 This represents the circle $|z-c|=r$ if 
 $p=1,g=-\bar c, q=r^2 - {|c|}^2$
The given equation can be written as 
 $w\bar w - {aw+\bar{a}\bar{w}\over {{|a|}^2-R^2}}+{1\over {{|a|}^2-R^2}} = 0 $ 
On comparing this with the first equation and making a few calculations more you will get the required expression.